# 17.04 Login loop after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login

I have dual booted Ubuntu 17.04 with Windows 10. 
On installing Nvidia 375.82 drivers manually, the computer goes into an Infinite Login Loop. 
Note:
I have tried everything 
1. chown root:root. Xauthority
2. purge the manually installex drivers and reinstall new ones
3. Reinstall Ubuntu and install the drivers.

The Installation of drivers was done after

> `sudo service lightdm stop`

One thing that I noticed was, after `service lightdm start` the loop started and `dpkg-configure lightdm` didn't give any output to select lightdm which was strange. Another thing was, the guest session login disappeared after installing nvidia drivers.

Nothing seems to work. Please help me out

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `ls -al /home/your_username/.*thority`.

Comment: That was a really bad idea to install drivers from a `.run` file.

Comment: I got it running now. All I did was disable on-board Intel graphics and then sudo Ubuntu-drivers autoinstall and voila it worked.

Comment: After the first kernel upgade it will stop working again.

Comment: I did reboot it once more to check that whether its working or not. Should I do it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on UBUNTU SERVER 16.04.3 on DELL POWER EDGE R830
My graphic card is GeForce 210 which required the 340.104 driver.

What I did was:

1. Identify your video card version:

   ```
   lspci | grep VGA
   ```
2. Find the driver at http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
3. Download the `.run` file
4. Run

   ```
   sudo chmod u+x <.run file>
   ```
5. Run

   ```
   ./<.run file>
   ```
6. The installation may give you the "pre-install" failed warning, just click on continue.
7. Reboot.
8. On BIOS setting of your system, DISABLE the embedded graphic card.

This should eliminate the infinite login loop problem. To verify that your driver is properly communicating with the video card(s) run:

```
nvidia-smi
```

It should show you the table of your video cards, CPU usage etc.